# HAProxy 2.0.2 is not creates 'srv' for all pods within the service

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy

I am trying to implement some cookie-based session stickiness with HAProxy inside of K8S cluster. I am using 2.0.2-alpine image.

In this environment I have 10 pods (all alive and ready) of some dummy web application StatefulSet, and HAProxy is pointed to their service by the following back-end:

```
backend within_session
  log global
  mode http
  option log-health-checks
  option httpchk GET /isalive
  balance roundrobin
  dynamic-cookie-key XXXXX
  cookie SESSION_COOKIE rewrite nocache dynamic
  option httpclose
  server-template srv 10 _http._tcp.dummywebapplication-service.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local resolvers k8s check
```

Although I set "srv" to maximum of 10 and I have 10 pods running, HAProxy created only 4 "srv"s.

Do have idea what could cause it?

Here are the relevant HAProxy logs:

```
<133>Jul 23 08:09:04 haproxy[7]: within_session/srv1 changed its FQDN from (null) to dummywebapplication-0.dummywebapplication-service.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local by 'SRV record'
<133>Jul 23 08:09:54 haproxy[7]: within_session/srv2 changed its FQDN from (null) to dummywebapplication-1.dummywebapplication-service.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local by 'SRV record'
<133>Jul 23 08:10:24 haproxy[7]: within_session/srv3 changed its FQDN from (null) to dummywebapplication-2.dummywebapplication-service.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local by 'SRV record'
<133>Jul 23 08:11:14 haproxy[7]: within_session/srv4 changed its FQDN from (null) to dummywebapplication-3.dummywebapplication-service.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local by 'SRV record'
<133>Jul 23 08:11:54 haproxy[7]: within_session/srv3 changed its FQDN from (null) to dummywebapplication-4.dummywebapplication-service.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local by 'SRV record'
<133>Jul 23 08:13:14 haproxy[7]: within_session/srv2 changed its FQDN from (null) to dummywebapplication-6.dummywebapplication-service.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local by 'SRV record'
<133>Jul 23 08:14:44 haproxy[7]: within_session/srv2 changed its FQDN from (null) to dummywebapplication-8.dummywebapplication-service.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local by 'SRV record'
<133>Jul 23 08:20:04 haproxy[7]: within_session/srv1 changed its FQDN from (null) to dummywebapplication-6.dummywebapplication-service.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local by 'SRV record'
<133>Jul 23 08:20:04 haproxy[7]: within_session/srv2 changed its FQDN from (null) to dummywebapplication-1.dummywebapplication-service.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local by 'SRV record'
<133>Jul 23 08:20:04 haproxy[7]: within_session/srv3 changed its FQDN from (null) to dummywebapplication-5.dummywebapplication-service.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local by 'SRV record'
```

Consider that the first 4 lines has srv1-4, and after that the srv ids was reused.

Comment: which version of haproxy do you use?

Comment: Hi @Aleksandar, HAProxy v2.0.2

Comment: intersting is that there are some missing numbers like `dummywebapplication-7..` do you get all pod ips from srv record? Are all pods in ready state? With the following command can you check that al pods have a ip `kubectl get ep dummywebapplication-service --namespace=mynamespace`

Comment: @Aleksandar yes, I get there the full pods list

Comment: @Aleksandar and it important to say that all of them are ready and alive

Comment: Is this the same question in haproxy discussion forum? https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/haproxy-k8s-and-server-template-unstable-fluctuating-server-list/4076 . Does it works with `8` ?

Comment: @Aleksandar yes, but it written by other person who reproduce it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `accepted_payload_size 8192` to the "revolvers" was fix that issue.